# Como sair da conta Office 365 automaticamente?

Tags: sso

Estou com dificuldades para utilizar um link que preste para fazer o logout do usuário no Office 365.

Os 3 exemplos abaixo fazer o logout, porém...

1) Neste primeiro exemplo o usuário tem que clicar no usuário, para que ele mande para fora (péssimo):

https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/logout

2) Neste segundo exemplo, o usuário é redirecionado para o msn (péssimo):

https://login.live.com/logout.srf

3) Neste terceiro exemplo, me aparece uma página em branco horrível que não diz nada:

https://login.live.com/oauth20_logout.srf

> Alguém tem uma sugestão de link que funcione e que faça apenas o logout com uma mensagem agradável...

Comment: Supondo que eu tenha entendido corretamente, tomara que não exista, senão qualquer engraçadinho põe o link numa meta tag ou src qualquer e desloga usuários sem confirmação. Já é dessa forma para não ter esse tipo de problema. Aliás, muitos sistemas são assim, justamente para evitar enganos e/ou má intenção.

Comment: @Bacco, sua informação não resolve o meu problema, mas eu vou deixar anotado aqui no meu caderno de notas de programação sobre segurança de contas e usuários para estudar mais tarde seu raciocínio ok.

Comment: Tem uma boa possibilidade de eu não ter entendido o problema. De qq forma foi o que eu vi de imediato se a idéia é deslogar o user de manera "não interativa".

Comment: A ideia é o usuário saber que foi deslogado por opção dele... (eu estou oferecendo um modal perguntando se ele deseja encerrar a conta da microsoft 365), se ele já disse que sim, porque eu precisaria de mais um etapa de escolha? Eu consigo matar a conta dele, se vc não notou, o exemplo 3 já faz isso, só que não de um jeito agradável... entendeu. Ali até o engraçadinho faz...

Comment: A ideia é fugir do iframe, péssima ideia mandar essa página por baixo dos panos...

Comment: _"se ele já disse que sim, porque eu precisaria de mais um etapa de escolha?"_ Pq é você que está afirmando que ele disse sim (e poderia não ser verdade), e a Microsoft teria nesse caso que confiar que vc está sendo "sincero". Sendo que o ideal seria você mandar ele para a MS dizendo que ele quer fechar, o usuário e a MS se entenderem. O que talvez fosse uma solução real seria você ter um endpoint da MS mais amistoso para integração (onde o usuário dissesse que quer se deslogar ou voltar para a sua aplicação, talvez).

Comment: Eu sei disso, mas eu tenho a client_id, ou seja, a partir do momento que eu estou utilizando um login efetuado em detrimento de um único acesso de app, ele por sua vez deveria me permitir deslogar o mesmo, através dessa client_id, não estou querendo encerrar todas as contas, mas somente a conta em questão onde ele acessa o conteúdo... específico. (e ele não está fazendo isso de forma inteligente, está muito mal feito... era pra ser só que não funciona, a [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc#single-sign-out) é muito confusa. :(

Comment: Deslogar o app nao é o mesmo que deslogar o user do 365. Eu tenho aplicações OAuth2 com logoff, e nesses casos se o user se desloga, eu descarto as credenciais da minha aplicação, pq ai nesse caso o token da sessão é "só meu". Não sei se você conseguiria aplicar algo nesse sentido no seu caso (nos meus, a negociação não é feita do lado do cliente em situações web, e sim no servidor).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui fazendo desta maneira:

```
$scope.redirectOutSistem = function() {
                loadingOn();
                //ESSA FUNCAO CONSTA NO ARQUIVO IS_MOBILE.JS
                try {
                    if (is_running_on_ipad) {
                        //ESSA FUNCAO SO FUNCIONA QUANDO É NO IPAD
                        sendObjectMessage({name: 'App', company: 'Name'});
                        window.location.href = '/sair';
                    } else if (is_running_on_android) {
                        Android.sendObjectMessage({name: 'App', company: 'Name'});
                    } else {
                        if (typeof is_login !== 'undefined' && is_login) {
                            loadingOff();
                        } else {
                            window.location.href = '/sair';
                        }
                    }

                } catch (e) {
                    //window.location.href = '/sair';
                }
            }

     $(document.body).append('<iframe data-logout-office365 style="display:none" src="https://login.live.com/oauth20_logout.srf" allow-same-origin allow-scripts></iframe>');
                            $.ajax({
                                url: "https://login.live.com/oauth20_logout.srf",
                                type: "POST",
                                crossDomain: true,
                                dataType: "text/html",
                                success: function (response) {
                                    $scope.redirectOutSistem();
                                    window.open('https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/logout','_blank');

                                },
                                error: function (xhr, status) {
                                    $scope.redirectOutSistem();
                                    window.open('https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/logout','_blank');
                                }
                            });
```

Comment: Essa coisa do OAuth2.0 depender de POST é chata até pra login, pra ser muito sincero. Eu acho que tem umas coisas bobas em certas especificações onde quem elabora se apega tanto à formalidade que esquece do objetivo da coisa. Entre elas é o fato de ficar quase (senão totalmente) impossível fazer um fluxo OAuth2.0 do lado do cliente sem JS (ou um botão).